# How to build web clips like http://brdrck.me/settings/

Tags: iphone, icons, mobile-safari, homescreen, web-clips

I am very interested in building an app like http://brdrck.me/settings/. My first questions are what is inside a web clip file? Is it a html or something else?  The second question is how to add the icon to home screens programmatically. As you can see from the page I mentioned above http://brdrck.me/settings/. I tried to check its source code from browser but it turns out to be some normal CSS and javascript code in my Chrome browser and I don't know how to check the source in my Mobile Safari. Any one help?

Comment: How about using a Proxy? Try [Charles Proxy](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) for checking the exact content delivered to your iPhone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't be able to get any valuable code from the source.  Trust me. :D

But, I can help you out.

I use two different methods: The "Add to Homescreen" and .mobileconfig files (the one you have  to install)

For adding to the homescreen check out this resource.  With the help of some creative work-arounds, it isn't too difficult.
http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/iphone-web-app-meta-tags/

The mobileconfig file is a bit more difficult, esp trying to get it signed, but this might help you a bit.  Try to create one with a webclip then view the generated files source: http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1465

Hope this helps.

Comment: mboileconfig's link doesn't avail.